# Leaking click event

Tags: arrays, button, angular-material, ngfor, ripple-effect

I'm having this problem related to **click events** in angular.
My application is a **tic-tac-toe app**.
My application uses **angular materials**.
**The problem:** when a user clicks a button on the board, the **click event seems to be leaking into a nearby button** on the board. The following **image demonstrates** what I'm talking about.
[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SRXx.png). As you can see, **the button in col 1 row 2 was activated even though that button was *not* clicked**. Below is a **blitz of my application.**

https://stackblitz.com/github/flashato9/tic-tac-toe

It would be great if I can get some help on this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Why you have declare Square component just for a button? Remove that component and directly bind the button in app component

Comment: Oh no no special reason. I'm new to angular so I'm testing things out. I tried your recommendation to put the button directly in the app.Component.html, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue using stackblitz or codesandbox?

Comment: Hey Vimal, I added a link to a stackblitz that shows the app.

Comment: there seems to same issue logged in github [link](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12132). As per the post instead of array of value use array of object

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with click event, it is the button ripple effect which is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks Vim, I got it working with the "array -> object" suggestion. You can see the progress in the blitz link. Also, what general steps did you use to debug this issue, because I was trying to debug earlier but I couldn't figure out what the issue was. btw I'm new to angular.

Comment: I did not debug at all, your application was working as expected, click event was firing was also correct. so I thought to google around ripple effect as that the only thing odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem Solved

Here is the [link](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12132) posted by Vimal Patel in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

really nice question =)

So the problem seems to be, that the mat button somehow responds to the change of the text cursor position.

if you change your *square.component.html* like so:

```html
<div class="grid-button"><span>{{value}}</span></button>
```

and change the *square.component.scss* like so:

```css
.grid-button{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(91, 158, 91);
  font-size: 10rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
.grid-button:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

when you now click a "button" you clearly see, that the cursor jumps to the next Field. But a simple `div` does not seem to react with `:hover` to that.

You can additionaly to the above CSS add `user-select: none;` to the `.grid-button` to not show the cursor or *maybe* a plain button (not Material) would also work.

*Long story short*: I would recommend not to use a Material Component if you change most of it's apperance, because there will probably allways be sideeffects.